# multiple repeating values, take the ones which are ticked

Tags: ms-access, vba

[image: This is the type of table I have in acce]

I need to see if all B column cells say yes for the specified column A number. If so I would like to print the value on a new table. If not ignore it.

In this particular case I would print A2 and A3.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate on the `A` column and then check to make sure that the count of records having a 'No' value in the `B` column is zero.

```
SELECT [A]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY [A]
HAVING SUM(IIF([B] = 'No', 1, 0)) = 0
```

@JohnInk edit:

If you want to also move the matching `A` values into a new table which you could then view, etc., you could use `SELECT ... INTO`:

```
SELECT [A]
INTO newTable
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY [A]
HAVING SUM(IIF([B] = 'No', 1, 0)) = 0
```

Comment: Add an INTO to print into a new table, like SELECT [A] INTO newtable GROUP BY [A] ect. ect.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!